# Why has "as it did" been used in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

> Coming as it did just after the success of The Shape of Water at the Oscars, the book became an instant bestseller.

I don't know what difference would it have made had I not used "as it did" after "coming".

Comment: A really good question!

Comment: In contexts like this, ***as it did*** is just a "standard format" *intensifier*. Specifically here drawing attention to the fact that of all the possible times when the book *could* have appeared, it's significant that it (just) happened to come out shortly after *The Shape of Water* did well in the Oscar awards (enabling the book to "coat-tail" its way to bestseller status). I think the only real difference is if you *do* include the intensifier, it's less likely that the book launch date was specifically chosen to take advantage of Oscar-related public interest, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a cross post of the [identical question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/210513/why-has-as-it-did-been-used-in-this-sentence) asked at ELL. (By somebody with the same username, even if a different account.)

Comment: @JasonBassford thoughtless crossposting is certainly discouraged, but it's not a reason for closure, and there are meta posts that confirm that crossposting is perfectly acceptable in some situations. This question should be closed as a *duplicate*...

Comment: @Chappo The cross-posting of *identical* questions certainly is a reason for closure, and no [meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) has said such would be acceptable.

Comment: @JasonBassford see the 3rd paragraph of the accepted answer. Even [this hostile comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu#comment1066562_64069) acknowledges "the impression that it's allowed to cross-post the identical same post to multiple sites and that tailoring your post to each site is better but not required." We close answers because they're ***off-topic on our site***, not because they also appear somewhere else in the SE network.

Comment: @Chappo I'm not going to recycle a lengthy debate in these comments. I will always vote to close any identical cross-post. You are free to put your own votes where you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of Auxiliaries to Avoid Repetition

Coming as it did just after the success of The Shape of Water at the Oscars, the book became an instant bestseller.

It can be phrased: The book became an instant bestseller, coming as it did just after the success of The Shape of Water at the Oscairs.

That order makes it easier to grasp that DID is an auxiliary replacement for the verb come:

> It avoids repetition: coming as it came just after etc.

Avoiding the repetition of the verb come is considered more elegant but it also reflects native use of English (all standard variants).

Avoiding repetition

It is often used when we want to avoid repeating a verb which we have already used in the first part of the sentence. Consider the following:

'Can I have another go with your game boy?' 'Yes, do!'
'She said she’d help me with the ironing and she did!'
'Did you see Maria when she was over in London?' 'Yes, I did!'

[avoiding repetition, BBC English](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/youmeus/learnit/learnitv80.shtml)\

[This is probably an ELL question rather than an ELU question]

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, "as it did" emphasizes causation between the timing if the book release and its sucess. Without "as it did," the correlation between the two clauses is less obvious.